# Customise javascript_include_tag output in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg

I'm trying to use a simple rails project to organise and maintain an SVG game. I'd like to use the built in asset pipeline to dynamically include my javascript *inside* the body of the output SVG file, but I can't work out the best way to get the correct script tag format.

I'm using this (application.js is my manifest file):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And I'm getting this (as expected):

```
<script src="/assets/scriptname.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I (think I) need this:

```
<script xlink:href="/assets/scriptname.js"></script>
```

Is there a sensible way to modify or override the tag attributes for javascript_include_tag?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why u need that, but))

```
= content_tag("script", "", { "xlink:href" => path_to_asset('scriptname.js') })
```

or

```
= javascript_include_tag "", {"type" => nil, "src" => nil, "xlink:href" => path_to_asset('scriptname.js') }
```

Comment: Ah amazing - that is so close! Do you know of a way to populate `path_to_asset()` with each file from the manifest `application.js`? As it is, I would need a `javascript_include_tag` for every file and to keep the list up to date.